# url rewriting with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My problem:
I want to write a .htaccess rule for.
`www.asdf.com/city.php?city=New-York` to `www.asdf.com/New-York`
but also with that I have other pages such as
`www.asdf.com/country.php?country=USA` which I would like to appear as `www.asdf.com/USA` and
`www.asdf.com/state.php?country=LA` which I would like to appear as `www.asdf.com/LA`

Pretty confused how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have identical url's for 3 completely different things, you are forced to use a php page to 'detect' what kind of 'thing' it is and 'route' your request to a specific page.

The following (untested) two rules will redirect all listed 'ugly' url's above to a fancy url and the fancy url to a php page that determines what page it should use for the request. `%2` is a back reference to the second capturing group in a RewriteCondition. The trailing `?` clears the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (city|country)=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (country\.php|city\.php|state\.php) %2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ myRouter.php?url=$1 [END]
```

With a file `myRouter.php` with something like:

```
<?php
  $url = $_GET['url'];

  if( isCity( $url ) ) {
    $city = $url;
    include( 'city.php' );
    exit();
  } elseif( isCountry( $url ) ) {
    $country = $url;
    include( 'country.php' );
    exit();
  }
  #etc....
?>
```

---

More logical would it be to use different fancy url's for different things, e.g. `/country/USA` for `country.php?country=USA`, `/state/LA` for `state.php?country=LA` and `/city/New-York` for `city.php?city=New-York`.

This can easily be done with the following (untested) htaccess and produces more logical url's:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (city|state|country)=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(country|city|state)\.php$ $1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(country|city|state)/(.*)$ $1.php?$1=$2 [END]
```